# Javascript - Problemas con punto decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un problema con un `script`, y resulta que estoy tratando de mostrar un `div` oculto `(#regalo)` **cuando el resultado de una suma es >xxx**, pero el problema es que sólo funciona con valores enteros ( *value="499"* ), y **no me funciona con decimales** en el `html` ( *value="499.99"* )...

`HTML`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function manageRegalo() {

    var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
    //var total = Number($("#total").val().replace(".",""));
    var total = Number($("#total"));
    if(totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
      total = totalStorage;
    }

  //if(total > 999.99 && total < 2999.99) { No funciona.

    if(total > 999 && total < 2999) { //Sin decimal funciona bien.

    $('#regalo').show();
    if (localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1') == null) {
      $('.tooltip').show();

      window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
      },9000);

      localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1', 'true')
    } // New - Local Storage for Tooltip
  } else {
    $('#regalo').hide();
  }
 }

  $(document).on('click', function (event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
      manageRegalo();

      //localStorage.setItem('total',Number($("#total").val().replace(".","")));
      localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total")));
    }
  });
  manageRegalo();
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display:none;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  
</style>


<div id="regalo">1</div>


<div id="ver-carrito">  
  <p>Productos en tu Carrito:</p>
  <div class="cont-num" id="clicksdos">0</div>
  <div id="cont-resultado"><p>Total a pagar:</p>

  <input name="total" id="total" readonly="readonly"> <!-- **** ID TOTAL **** -->

  </div>
</div>



<div id="cont-p1" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-1">
  Producto 1<br><br>499 €
  <input class="add-prod" value="499" readonly="readonly">
  <!-- value="499.99" El script no funciona -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-p2" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-2">
  Producto 2<br><br>299 €
  <input class="add-prod" value="299" readonly="readonly">
  <!-- value="299.99" El script no funciona -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cont-p3" class="cont-p">
  <div id="producto-3">
  Producto 3<br><br>399 €
  <input class="add-prod" value="399" readonly="readonly">
  <!-- value="399.99" El script no funciona -->
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Nota 1**: El valor "***499***" del primer ejemplo `html` ... (sin decimal) funciona bien. Pero si el
>    valor = "***499.99***" (con punto decimal), mi `script` ya no funciona correctamente, suma los valores pero no muestra el `div` oculto. Los mismo pasa con otros **valores con decimales** ( 3.99 - 5.99 - 9.99 ...)
>
> **Nota 2**: He borrado el `.val().replace(".","")` del `script` pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Falta `#total`.

Comment: @ArtEze ... No falta '#total' ... La página está completa y la estoy usando sin problemas, salvo lo importante que es que el script publicado *no me reconoce* los '"value=xx.xx"' esto es, con punto decimal...

Comment: Me refería a que falta ese `div` con el `id="total"` en el _HTML_. De todos modos publiqué una respuesta, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Aún con las ediciones, falta la función que calcula el total, y los div con class `comp-clone` y `bbp`

Answer (score 1):

Para calcular el total solo hay que hacer esto:

```
var total = eval(Array.from($(".add-prod").map((a,b)=>$(b).val())).join("+"))
$("#total").val(total)
```

Lo que hago es buscar todos los productos, que tienen class `.add-prod`.

```
$(".add-prod")
```

Luego busco sus valores mediante `.val()`, entonces recorro el array con `.map`

```
.map((a,b)=>$(b).val())
```

A todo eso le hago un `Array.from` para convertirlo a un array, que es la lista de precios.

```
Array.from($(".add-prod").map((a,b)=>$(b).val()))
```

El array quedaría así:

```
[499.99, 299, 399]
```

Por último los uno con un `+` con `.join` para luego hacer el cálculo mediante `eval`.

```
499.99+299+399
```

Además agrego el resultado en `#total`:

```
$("#total").val(total)
```

Comment: Gracias @ArtEze ... Voy a estudiar tu propuesta y hacer cambios en mi trabajo. Si tengo problemas vuelvo a comentar. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

pongale al input el `type="text"`, luego en javascript use `Number(valor)`.

```
<input id="total" type="text" class="add-prod" value="499" readonly="readonly">

var total = Number($("#total").val());
```

ahora si no tiene id de los input utilice el html padre para recorrer el valor de los hijos con un for y use class para identificarlos.